# differentiate $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Tags: derivatives

> $$\frac{d}{dx}ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=\frac{1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

$t=\sqrt{x^2-1}$

$$\frac{1-\frac{x}{t}}{x+t}=\frac{1}{x+t}-\frac{x}{t(x+t)}=\frac{t-x}{t(x+t)}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-x}{(\sqrt{x^2-1})(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}$$

I can get to the end result of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Comment: Alternatively, one can use that (1) $\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}) = \operatorname{arcosh}(x)$, (2) $\cosh'(x) = \sinh x$, and (3) $\sinh^2 x + 1 = \cosh^2 x$.

Comment: Replace $\frac{d}{dx}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ by $\frac{d}{dx}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.

Comment: First line: how does the minus sign appear in the numerator when you differentiated $ \ x^2 \ - \ 1 \ $ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a wrong sign:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=
\frac{1\mathbin{\color{red}{+}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$